# How do I find out if BMP image contains BGR or BGRA pixels from header?

Tags: c++, bmp

I can't figure out how do I find out if BMP image contains BGR or BGRA colors. I wrote simple BMP reader but there are different values on different images.

There are 2 options I have found out already.

1. Simple BGR (255, 255, 255)
2. Fourth value is 0 (255, 255, 255, 0)

Is there any way how do I find out which option is that from bitmap info header?

Comment: It's complicated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first 54 bytes in the bitmap file is the header. Read [`BITMAPINFOHEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx) which contains bitmap's width and height, as well as `biBitCount`

For a 32-bit (4-byte) image `biBitCount` is 32 (BGRA)
For a 24-bit (3-byte) image `biBitCount` is 24 (BGR)

`biBitCount` can also be 16-bit, or 8, 4, 1 for palette based bitmaps.

Comment: I have downloade a sample picture from some Microsoft website which is 8 bit BMP. I tried to read that picture and every fourth color of *each* pixel is 0. How is that possible? It can't be BGR, because first, second and third colors matches.

Comment: 8-bit bitmap (256 colors) has palette. The palette size is 1024 bytes (256 colors * 4-bytes). The pixels start after 54+1024, and these pixels are not BGR values, it is an index to the palette. In this case each pixel is only 1-byte